# Cut file name into two parts in unix

Tags: unix, split, cut

I have a requirement to cut a file name into two parts.
So my file name is : `'SIC_ETL_MAIN_0.1.zip'`
I want to cut the file name into parts and load into two variable separately
Expected Output:

```
SIC_ETL_MAIN - var1
0.1 - var2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using grep

```
$echo SIC_ETL_MAIN_0.1.zip |  grep -o '[A-Z_]*[A-Z]'
SIC_ETL_MAIN
$echo SIC_ETL_MAIN_0.1.zip |  grep -o '[0-9\.]*[0-9]'
0.1
$
```

Edit: Variable assignment

```
$var1=$(echo SIC_ETL_MAIN_0.1.zip |  grep -o '[A-Z_]*[A-Z]')
$var2=$(echo SIC_ETL_MAIN_0.1.zip |  grep -o '[0-9\.]*[0-9]')
$echo "Var1=${var1}  Var2=${var2}"                                                
Var1=SIC_ETL_MAIN  Var2=0.1
$
```

Answer (score 0):

If your shell happens to be bash (or another shell wit shubstrings)

```
a=SIC_ETL_MAIN_0.1.zip
b=${a%_*}
c=${a##*_}
d=${c%.*}

echo "$a | $b | $c | $d" # will output
SIC_ETL_MAIN_0.1.zip | SIC_ETL_MAIN | 0.1.zip | 0.1
```